# How to get the row value of a ListView using the row number?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new here and a VB.net newbie.
Is there any way that we can get row value and display it to a Label using a row number.
For example, if a number generated is `4`, is there any code that could get the values from the very 4th row of the ListView item?

```
 Sub Display_NameList() 
     Me.Name_ListView.Items.Clear()
     CONNECTION.Close()
     CONNECTION.Open()

     Query = "Select * From name_listing Where Raffle_Indicator='1'"
     comm = New MySqlCommand(Query, CONNECTION)
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
     Reader = comm.ExecuteReader

     While Reader.Read
         Dim lv As ListViewItem
         lv = Name_ListView.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Reader("ID") & ""))
         lv.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(Reader("Name") & ""))
         lv.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(Reader("Office") & ""))
     End While 
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a ListView control and not a ListBox? If it's a ListView, how did you set the View property (List, Details...). What do you mean with *if a number generated is 4 (...)*. What is *generating* this number? Is this number always in the range of `1` to the number of items in the list? Is this *generation* an event of sort (e.g., a Button Click)?

Comment: I could also use a listbox. I'm really actually looking for options.

Comment: Dim index As Integer = rnd.Next(Name_ListView.Items.Count)

        Label2.Text = Name_ListView.Items.Count.ToString(index)

Comment: Number generated from that code.

Comment: So, you want something like:  `Label2.Text = Name_ListView.Items(index).Text`?

Comment: Yes the number ranges from 1 to the number of the last item on the list.

Comment: At this moment the range is `0 - Name_ListView.Items.Count - 1`. The Random class max value is exclusive (is not in range).

Comment: In a way. Yes. But it should at least get the value of say column 1 from the list. Like if the columns are ID - Name. the return value that should display would be the ID column.

Comment: You can get all the values you want, but you have to make it clear how your ListView items are defined. Do the Items have Sub-Items? Can you post the code that generates the ListView content (not in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54394829/edit) your question )?

Comment: Cause you see I have label2 and label3. Label2 to should display the generated number, right. And my code is already running it successfully. Now I want label3 to get the value from column 1 which labeled as ID. from the row that should be equal to label2.

Comment: There you go. sorry new here. Thanks. :)

Comment: This: `Label3.Text = Name_ListView.Items(index).Text` already does that.

Comment: oh shoot. thanks. it actually did the job. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

An example for listbox

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim codici As String() = {"cod1", "cod2", "cod3", "cod4", "cod5", "cod6"}
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.DataSource = codici
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Not (ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then
            Label1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No selection")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```